# Places where assignment operator can be used wrongly instead of comparison operator , = Vs ==

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, compiler-warnings

I'm doing a C++ compiler project where I need to flag warnings at places where assignment operator can be used wrongly instead of the comparison operator. .e.g
while doing comparison in `if` statement , to check variable `a` as `10` sometimes we wrongly type if(`a`= `10`), which will result in `if` statement always `true` whereas I wanted to be true only if `a` is `10`. Some of the cases I can think of are :

1. `if(var = a)`, logically it should be `if( var==a )`
2. `while(var = a )`
3. `for(;var=a;)`
4. `do{}while(var=a)`
5. `var=a? "some XYZ": "some ABC"`

Can you please help me with the more cases where this logical error can occur, where the user was supposed to use `==` and by mistake `=` was used?

Comment: How about the other way around, where comparison was used instead of assignment? I've seen it a couple of times.

Comment: As for your "problem", some compilers can detect this and warn about it. And there are many good statical analysis tools that will detect such issues (and many more) as well.

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time with this if I were you. Sometimes you *want* an assignment as a loop conditional, such as in string copy idioms. Sometimes you want a comparison when normally you'd write an assignment. IMHO folk just need to have the difference drummed into them.

Comment: What language are you compiling?

Comment: Writing a static analysis tool is a nice project, but if you wanna do something great, give the option of signalling the thing is intentional. Just because this use may seem a mistake to *you*, doesn't mean it's a mistake *period*. I mean, just consider what Bathsheba told you.

Comment: @Batsheba [if you say so...](https://ideone.com/N2pUrY)

Comment: Language : Both C and C++

Comment: No, please choose one. There's a subtle difference. The type of the result of `a == b` is an `int` in C, and a `bool` in C++, for example.

Comment: I'm more interested in bad logic creation. That's why mentioned both C, C++. More interested in cases first. Thinking about cases

Comment: In C and C++. assignments are legal in all these places (except case 5 doesn't mean what you probably think it means). If a *truth value* is expected in a certain context, issue a *warning* if an assignment is found there *without parentheses*. If you are writing a compiler, you should know exactly which contexts expect truth values: those that generate conditional jumps or similar code.

Comment: @StoryTeller: There's already a reasonable idiom: `if (static_cast<bool>(*p++=*q++))`. This requires no particular tool support

Comment: @MSalters - It certainly does require tool support. If the tool is poorly written and flags any assignment in the `if(...)` as a mistake... well..

Comment: @StoryTeller: Well, that would be a bug for many more cases - just consider lambda expressions in there. Limited parsing of C++ is _very_ hard; there's no easy way to skip parts you don't care about.

Comment: @MSalters - Most certainly. Which why I considered it a nice project :)

Answer (score 5):

A nasty one I ran across recently was `assert (a=b)`. The reason that's so particularly nasty is because the assumption stated in the assert is that the two are already equal, so the statement is most likely harmless. But if they aren't, this sets you up for a nasty debugging session as the debug builds functionally differs from the release build.

Comment: This one is pure evil

Comment: Well, using assignment in `assert` is *always* wrong.